# Wordpress: how to implement a sequence of pages other than template hierarchy

Tags: wordpress

Being fairly new to Wordpress, I’m trying to understand how to implement a sequence of pages other than the sequence suggested by the template hierarchy.

Consider (as an example) a website where different products can be purchased. We have the custom post type “products”. Products can be selected and added to the cart. When the user wants to check out, he will be offered a sequence of pages for doing the checkout for one or more products.

What would be the best way to implement such a sequence? In normal websites, it is just a number of pages linking to each other. In Wordpress, at the time of writing the code the page id’s are unknown and will only be known after creating the pages in wp admin. After this, we can use the page id’s, but when rolling out to a different environment (for example from development to test or live), we have to create the pages again in wp admin, resulting in new page id’s. The page id’s will have to be altered in code. This is undesirable in my opinion, error prone, right?

Is there a way of dealing with this in Wordpress other than synchronizing databases? In other words, what is the best design for implementing a sequence of pages linking to each other, other than the normal wordpress template hierarchy flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I created a way to access permalinks based on logical id's both from php and javascript. When rolling out to a different environment only the mappings from logical id's to urls should be changed in one array in functions.php and you're done.

To enqueue your .js file in functions.php:

```
wp_register_script( 'aom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'aom_script', 'my_js_permalinks', aom_get_page_permalinks() );
wp_enqueue_script('aom_script');
```

Code in functions.php for storing and accessing the permalinks:

```
function aom_get_page_permalinks() {
    $page_permalinks = array(
      "home"=>get_bloginfo('url'),
      "someurl"=>get_permalink(14),
      "anotherurl"=>get_permalink(16)
    );
    return $page_permalinks;
}

function aom_get_page_permalink($page_id) {
    $page_permalinks = aom_get_page_permalinks();
    return $page_permalinks[$page_id];
}
```

Now if you need a permalink in php:

```
aom_get_page_permalink('someurl');
```

And if you need a permalink in javascript:

```
my_js_permalinks.someurl;
```